# Is it a liability to use the lightning container npm package? (not been updated for 4 years...)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, security-review, react

I have embedded my react app in a lightning container iframe as the docs suggest.

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:container src="{!$Resource.myReactApp + '/index.html'}"/>
</aura:component>
```

I now want to make calls to the Salesforce API via Apex.  The docs suggest to do this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.lightning.meta/lightning/container_npm_callApex.htm

```
    LCC.callApex("lcc1.ApexController.getAccount",
                 this.state.name,
                 this.handleAccountQueryResponse,
                 {escape: true});
  }
```

My concern is this LCC (lightning container) npm package was last published 4 years ago.  Is this a cause for concern?  Are there alternatives?  Do others currently use LCC in production apps?  Will this be a liability for the security review?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, it's not been updated in four years because no changes have been needed. `lightning:container` is the proper way to host non-Lightning components in Aura, including React, Vue, Svelte, and many more frameworks in a secure way. The LCC API provides the necessary connectivity to use Salesforce features.